# How to administer computer when no inbound connection is possible?

Tags: connection

I have to periodically administer my parent's Linux computer, because they are too old to understand how to do this themselves. Computer is in the remote location. I always used ssh through the port forwarding on the router. However, their provider recently removed the ability to make any inbound connection and my ssh doesn't connect any more.

My question is: what is the next best way to administer it?

I know that VPN can possibly be used. I can (maybe) set up VPN network with this computer.
Also I can make it try to connect with ssh to my home computer on a particular port for ex. every 15 minutes, establishing the port forwarding back to it. Custom shell script should be used for this.

But what are the alternatives?
Any other, nicer way to be able to connect to this Linux machine from outside?

Comment: You may have better chances on http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/. You can use your stack overflow login to make an account.

Comment: If there's a gui on the pc you can use teamviewer or similar alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your suggestion: get your parents to run a script (all they would have to do is double click something) which ssh's to your computer, and then run back on that?